# how to add an ordinal factor to the dataframe in r

Tags: r

I'm new here and new to r programming and hope that you can help me with:

I have the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
gender<-sample(c("M","F"),size=100,replace=TRUE)
mark<-round(rnorm(100,mean=55,sd=10),0)
```

How can I add  an  ordinal  factor  to  my  dataframe  showing  the  grade  A-E that each student has, where A=85-100, B=70-84, C=55-69, D=40-
54, E=25-39.

Many thanks for your kind help

Comment: mean score of 55. tough class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` to divide the scores into 5 bins. The `labels` argument allows you to provide the names of the groups.

The range of the bins will have the pattern, `start < x <= end`. That means the lowest is not included. Therefore a score of `25` will result in `NA`, so we make the argument `include.lowest=TRUE`:

```
cut(mark, c(25, 40, 55, 70, 85, 100), labels=rev(LETTERS[1:5]), include.lowest=TRUE)
#[1] C B C B C D B B C B D B C B B C A C C D..
```

Comment: thanks Pierre for the kind help. I have tried to run the code and create a table with the grade. this is what i have got:   gender mark x
1        M   59 C
2        M   49 B
3        F   58 C
4        F   44 B
5        M   69 C
6        F   75 D
7        F   51 B
8        F   45 B
9        F   61 C
10       M   54 B
11       M   79 D
12       M   55 B
13       F   62 C

Comment: someone with mark 49 has b grade, where did i went wrong?

Comment: That's not your fault, I have to reverse the grades so that the lowest is E not A. I'll edit.